# Several answers to single question; one answer or split into separate answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Since there are "Shivi'im Panim LeTorah" (70 faces to Torah), often there may be several answers to the same question. This is often the case when someone asks for the reason for a custom, or to interpret a posuk. Should I put all the answers I know into one answer, or split each independent answer into a separate answer?

For example I have some more reasons to add to [Why do we beat the arava?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20263/why-do-we-beat-the-arava). Should I add them to my existing answer, or as a new answer?

Comment: It seems R' Isaac Moses has paskined: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4513687#4513687

Comment: @DoubleAA, though it's possible the mi-yodeya series is different enough from other questions that we shouldn't rule based on that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio We shouldn't rule based on some individual's "pesak" in chat, regardless!

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, it was more just a not so funny way of pointing out whatever precedent there was.

Comment: @IsaacMoses But what if he's a Gadol HaDor???

Answer (score 3):

votes generally tell if the community thinks that answers are good (or bad). For example, an answer with +10 is considered good, -10 is considered bad, 0 is considered bleh, +5/-5 is controversial.

With two answers, there is no way for one to see with what the community agrees.

For example, a question like "Do May I cook milk and meat together" can have an answer like "SA says no (See YD Siman 87)" and "No, because aliens told me that one MUST eat milk and meat". Answer one is good. Answer two is bad. If this answer has 5 upvotes, does that mean that the community respects answer one, two, or either? There is no way to tell.

Comment: On a site like meta, where you're up- and down-voting the *idea*, I think this is valid, but the criteria for a good answer on the main site is that it shows research effort (and if so, one good answer in a question might qualify)

Comment: @ba some answers can be good (well-researched, accurate) and some can be sloppy. Do you upvote an answer which has good answers if it also has bad (as in not-researched and incorrect) answer?

Comment: The one good answer shows research effort. I wasn't saying that your reason is invalid — I'm undecided about it (if you noticed, I said "might" in my comment and didn't downvote the answer). I was just giving another possible way of viewing it

Comment: @ba explained myself

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from the point of view of the one reading the answer, it is much easier to have them all in one answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. If it's by one writer it's appropriate to keep them all together.
2. Even when there are different answers (70 faces) they usually come in one *mylech*(? מהלך) as different opinions on the same thing, so they can be brought together.
3. Numbering can be used for different answers (or horizontal lines if they're really long).